# Where can I set umask for system account?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, umask

I have created a system account that's used by some process specifically. I want to set `umask 002` for  it. For regular user account, I usually put configuration like this in `.profile`. This approach is not suitable for system account, as `.profile` is sourced at login and system account doesn't require login.

Where can I set `umask 002` for system account?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36220/how-to-set-umask-for-a-system-user

Answer (score 0):

On most Linux systems, it is usually set in `/etc/profile`, but it can also be set in `/etc/bashrc`.

The latter gets sourced for all `bash` script invocations, not just logins.

However, if the system process is not started from a `bash` script, then you'll need to use a PAM configuration.

Answer (score 0):

edit `/etc/profile` and try this:

```
if [ `id -u` -eq $user_id_to _change ]; then
   umask 002
else
   umask 022
fi
```

of course you have to change `$user_id_to_change` to the user id of which you want to change the umask. than reboot.
this code snippet defenitly works with "normal" users. cant imagine, why this shouldnt work with system users.